# Por que a imagem fica com qualidade ruim?

Tags: java, android, bitmap

Bem, a pergunta é simples, por que a imagem fica em qualidade baixa?

Código:
Classe Main:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");

            Intent imageActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ImageActivity.class);
            imageActivity.putExtra("image", imageBitmap);
            startActivity(imageActivity);
        }
    }
```

Classe Image:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bitmap image = intent.getParcelableExtra("image");

this.image.setImageBitmap(image);
```

Imagens:

Imagem original:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Imagem na activity Image:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Porque `extras.get("data");` retorna a foto em tamanho reduzido(*Thumbnail*). Veja na [documentação](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPath) como obter a foto em tamanho real.

Comment: Obrigado ramaral

Comment: tente isso aqui : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31445156/how-to-take-a-picture-to-show-in-a-imageview-and-save-the-picture

Comment: Eu já consegui, mas obrigado de qualquer jeito, eu não sei "marcar como resolvido"

Comment: @OsvaldoCésar Se já conseguiu resolver o ideal é colocar a sua resolução como resposta, com as respetivas explicações sobre o problema e de como ultrapassou o problema. Assim consegue ajudar outras pessoas que tenham o mesmo problema.